# Is it possible to use 2 DVI ports and 1 DisplayPort on a W530 laptop?

Tags: thinkpad, dvi, displayport, nvidia-quadro

I have Lenovo W530 laptop with Quadro K1000M graphics card with a docking station.

I can connect 2 DVI + 1 VGA but I cannot connect 2 DVI + 1 DisplayPort.

Is there some inherent limitation while using DVI + DisplapyPort?

Comment: VGA is `Analog`. DVI and Displayport is `Digital`.  `Digital to Analog` cables do exist.  If this doesn't answer your question clarify your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Why you no put an answer?

Comment: @Griffin - I don't answer questions that can be answered by doing a Google search.  Unless I know what I have said is helpful I won't bother with an answer, there are far to many people on this network, who will dowonvote my answers out of spite.

Comment: Where are the ports?  You're trying to use the mini DisplayPort on the laptop, and there are 2 DVI ports on the dock?  What does Device Manager show under the Display Adapters when docked?

Comment: @ernie - The ports exists on docking station. It's displayport connection  and not mini Displayport via http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?DocID=PD021624. The Device manager shows Generic PnP Monitor.

Comment: @Ramhound- I have VGA cable. I don't want to use VGA. It's inferior in quality to DVI and Displayport cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the real answer [is here](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&DocID=PD024298), where it describes what I believe is your dock:

> Mini Dock Plus (90W & 170W): 1x VGA, 2x DVI, 2x DP
>
> Many systems allow for two of these video ports to be used simultaneously. Select systems, including those with NVIDIA Optimus technology, allow for up to three video ports on the dock to be used simultaneously.

More details about this can be seen in the [user's guide](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/options_iso/433815u_433835u_0a36707.pdf), which shows a line separating out the first two video ports (a DisplayPort and a DVI) from the second ground of ports (DisplayPort, DVI, and VGA).

Finally, some hints at [this link](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-76617), showing how to get 3 external displays. Looks like for the W530, you have to have the 170W dock for 3 external displays. The schematic at the end of that page suggests the first pair of ports (DP and DVI) is one, the second set is another, and the VGA is another display.

Answer (score 3):

Some video cards have limitations.  I have a video card where the HDMI slot and the 2nd DVI slot share a connection.  You can use one or the other.  I'm sure this is probably the case in your situation with the DVI and DP ports.  Also, does your Display Port use an adapter to DVI?  If so, you may need to purchase what is called an "Active" adapter for Display Port to DVI.  Without an active adapter, you will be limited to how many screens you can operate.

Comment: I have  two display, two DVI  and one VGA distinct port on my docking station. That made me think that I might be able to use 5 monitors :). I could use 3 with DVI,DVI,VGA or DVI,DisplayPort,VGA combination. I hate VGA but I guess stuck with it. I have pure Displayport to Displayport cable. I think you are correct in saying this is limitation of graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

There are two digital video ports on the laptop. You can use a DVI or Displayport with each in any combination. The ports on the dock are clearly labelled: there's a DVI and a Displayport for one, and a DVI and a Displayport for the other. IF you try to plug in three monitors using these sockets you are plugging two monitors into one port, and it simply doesn't work.

The only way to get three monitors is if one of them is VGA.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but the provided by ernie does explain this. Here is the image from the support site : http://support.lenovo.com/ContentResources/Migrated%20Assets/pc/support/site_wss/76617_4338rearview.jpg

Comment: Not strictly true - you can use two DVI and one DisplayPort as long as the DisplayPort is connected directly to the laptop mini one rather than the docl. https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht037605  But you are right about the fact that only one or the other on the dock can be used.